# What is difference between $? vs $^ in gnu make?

Tags: gnu-make

Referring to https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables

$?
The names of all the prerequisites that are newer than the target, with spaces between them. If the target does not exist, all prerequisites will be included. For prerequisites which are archive members, only the named member is used (see Archives).

$^
The names of all the prerequisites, with spaces between them. For prerequisites which are archive members, only the named member is used (see Archives). A target has only one prerequisite on each other file it depends on, no matter how many times each file is listed as a prerequisite. So if you list a prerequisite more than once for a target, the value of $^ contains just one copy of the name. This list does not contain any of the order-only prerequisites; for those see the ‘$|’ variable, below.

The 2 operators look very similar and so I am wondering when they will be different.

Comment: I mean, the text pretty much tells you the difference.  `$?` expands to the prerequisites _that are newer_ than the target.  `$^` expands to _all_ the prerequisites of the target.

Comment: Try an example where one of the prerequisites is newer than the target and another one is older.

Comment: The difference is important when you consider the difference between tools like a linker, where you build the output from scratch so you always need to provide ALL the prerequisites (`$^`) and an archiver (`ar`) where you can replace only the updated parts but not replace any parts that are not updated (then you might use `$?`)

Comment: Or, if you just want to print some info on what prerequisites have been changed :)